# How to overwrite Materialize CSS with browser default CSS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-table, angular-datatables

I'm making a web application using Javascript, AngularJS and Materialize CSS for my UI. Materialize CSS has been a great tool so far but I have a problem.

I want to use Angular-Datatables for my tables but I can't because they're being manipulated by Materialize CSS. You don't even have to write anything special, you just write `<table>` and you're already using Materialize's table.

So my question is: how do I keep using Materialize CSS for everything else, but use the default tables' CSS so I can use Angular-Datatables?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Here's my HTML code:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width:15%"><b>ID</b></th>
            <th style="width:40%"><b>Title</b></th>
            <th style="width:15%"><b>Start Date</b></th>
            <th style="width:20%"><b>End Date</b></th>
            <th style="width:10%"><b>Type</b></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="task in tasks track by $index">
            <td>{{task.id}}</td>
            <td>{{task.title}}</td>
            <td>{{task.start_day}} {{task.start_time}}</td>
            <td>{{task.end_day}} {{task.end_time}}</td>
            <td>{{task.type}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This code produces the following table:

[image]

With angular-datatables, and if you follow their site you just need to change the `<table>` tag to `<table datatable="">`, it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Are you using SASS or the pre-built Materialize? If you are using SASS simply remove any <table> styling.

Comment: If you are using pre-built Materialize and Angular-Datatables, I assume you are calling the datatables CSS somewhere in `<head>`, be sure you are calling it after Angular-Materialize CSS.

Comment: Please post an example of your code for a more definitive answer.

Comment: I guess I'm using pre-built Materialize, I'm certainly not using the SASS version. And yes, I'm loading the angular-datatables CSS after the Materialize CSS. My code is just a basic table in plain HTML. But when you include the Materialize CSS that table automatically becomes the table from Materialize. But angular-datatables is supposed to be used with the normal default table. When you use angular-datatables with a Materialize table it becomes a jumbled mess.

Comment: @RichardHowell check my EDIT for my code and images of what the problem looks like.

Answer (score 2):

You have three choices:

1.) Identify the offending rules added by Materialize and overwrite them to match the styling you require in your own style sheet

2.) Use the un-minified version of Materialize and remove the offending styles

3.) Remove any table styling from Materialize source and compile the SASS yourself (https://prepros.io/ this should work to compile your SASS)